# Error: Field X "has changed type from NUMERIC to FLOAT" when INSERTing data to BigQuery with load_table_from_json

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to add data to a BigQuery table using the official Python SDK.

When I pass some JSON into the [`load_table_from_json(data, table)` function](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_json), the API response complains that one of my values is a `FLOAT` in the dataset, but the table's schema says that column is `NUMERIC`. The value is `0.0`.

Since JSON doesn't have explicit data types, it's confusing how/why the API would think that it's a FLOAT type, or how I could force it to know otherwise. I would think that BigQuery's API would be smart enough to know that the value could be safely inserted into either column type.

The full error message is:

```
400 Provided Schema does not match Table my-project:my-dataset.my-table. Field count_purchased has changed type from NUMERIC to FLOAT
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this is to explicitly [specify your own schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#TableSchema) to tell BigQuery this is a `NUMERIC` value. This is done by passing a `LoadJobConfig` when calling `load_table_from_json(data, table, job_config=my_job_config)`.

Here's how I defined the schema for my load job. Notice that the only thing I needed to pass in was the schema definition; the rest of the defaults worked fine.

```py
my_schema = [
  {
    "name": "count_purchased",
    "type": "NUMERIC"
  },{
    "name": "_load_datetime",
    "type": "DATETIME"
  }
]

my_job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=my_schema)

client = bigquery.Client()
client.load_table_from_json(data, table, job_config=my_job_config)
```

This is necessary because the `load_table_from_json` method will try to create its own `LoadJobConfig` object if one is not explicitly passed in [[source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/bigquery-1.24.0/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L1948)]. The load job by default will have [`autodetect=true`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad.FIELDS.autodetect). It seems that auto-detection on the BigQuery server-side is not aware of the existing schema. In other words: it defaults to `FLOAT` any time there's a decimal in the value, even when its destination column is `NUMERIC` and the value is compatible with that data type. The same thing happens if you try to insert an un-quoted number into a `STRING` column.

Comment: I also think that custom schema is a good approach to force a data type. It is worth of mentioning that BigQuery has conversion rules that can be applied depending on certain rules, more infor about it in [Conversion rules in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules).